# Copying to clipboard, hidde char

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm using some js code to copy text to the clipboard, but when I've some strings with `\` char it doesn't appear when I paste the string.
Do you know how to fix this?

Ex.

String "aaa\a" and paste "aaaa"

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure there's really a backslash in the string? If it's a string literal, backslash is the escape character. You need to escape the backslash to make it literal, by writing `"aaa\\a"`

Comment: Without seeing your code my ASSUMPTION is that you are including a escape character and not a literal.  Please paste your code so we can best help you.

Comment: I've createad a function 

function copyToClipboard(text){
 navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
}

and use it like 

copyToClipboard('aaa\a');

Answer (score -1):

Backslash is an escape character and is, therefore, not printed. `\n` is a well-known escape sequence. The `\` escapes the text and allows for `n`, which, in turn, creates a new line. In your example, the `\\` escape sequence can be used. Essentially, `aaa\\a` will paste as `aaa\a`